# Regex for getting values from JSON block

Tags: json, regex, python-3.x

Could someone rectify the error I am making while grouping a JSON data block for generating key, value tuples list. I am able to collect all key,value pairs except the last pair which ends with `}`. I don't seem to understand why or `|` alternation is not working for the last pair.

```
\"(.*?)\"[:]+\"?(.*?)\"?[,[^\s](?=\")|[^\s]\}$]
```

I am using Python's `re.findall` function to generate the groups.

Example data block :

```
{
"author_flair_text": null,
"author": "joeinfro",
"id": "d2nvjik",
"link_id": "t3_4h4boa",
"gilded": 0,
"created_utc": 1462060800,
"author_flair_css_class": null,
"parent_id": "t3_4h4boa",
"ups": 1,
"body": "thats 1 case per 5000 people. nice!",
"subreddit_id": "t5_2qh13",
"stickied": false,
"edited": false,
"subreddit": "worldnews",
"distinguished": null,
"score": 1,
"retrieved_on": 1465550534,
"controversiality": 0
}
```

EDIT : Finally found the solution for it. Made use of non-capturing group of regex.

**Solution :**

```
\"(.*?)\"[:]+\"?(.*?)\"?(?:,(?=\")|\}$)
```

`

Comment: You should provide some example input/output for us. The general case would be impossible (i think) because JSON can have nested structures.

Comment: Don't understand your regex. Among other things it has double quotes while your example has (mostly) single ones... Try with `(?:'([^']*)'|"([^"]*)")\s*:\s*(?:'([^']*)'|"([^"]*)")`. [Check it here](https://regex101.com/r/iY5dK1/2).

Comment: Updated the example. My bad, I pasted the converted `dictionary` content.